# Azure Data Lake Analytics and querying data from linked data source (blob)

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-blob-storage

I would like to access/read/store file from linked (external) blob storage account - not from primary data lake store account. I added a new Data Source (external blob) in Azure Portal.

How can I specify that I need to read from external blob?

I found syntax in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-get-started) (following example), but I do not understand what means **BlobContainerName** :

```
 wasb://<BlobContainerName>@<StorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/Samples/Data/SearchLog.tsv
```

Thank you in advance

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the name of your container. See [Blob Service Concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#blob-service-concepts).  See also, [WASB_Path_URI (Windows Azure Blob Storage Path URI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt771650.aspx#wasbpath).

Comment: Thank you. 

In my blob storage account looks the path as follows: `mytestblobaccount.blob.core.windows.net/samples/Data/SearchLog.tsv`

Therefore I have to use following link:

    `wasb://samples@mytestblobaccount.blob.core.windows.net/Data/SearchLog.tsv`